# What is the one word for someone who gets worried and anxious too fast, usually over silly things?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a single word for someone who gets worried and anxious very fast, usually over silly things? An adjective that can be used to fill in the blank in:

> My mother is very _______
>
> I want to tell my mother about my flight tonight, but, you know, she is __________ and will lose her sleep worrying over my safety.

Comment: Is there a reason why *anxious* itself doesn't work for you? When used without qualification (just anxious in general, not anxious *about* or *for* or *because of* anything) I would take it to mean what you describe.

Comment: I imagine you're talking about a character like the "Don't Panic" guy from the show Dad's Army

Comment: "My mother is a worrier", "Don't mention it to her, she's a worrier", ... common usage in UK at least.

Comment: @nigel222 We say that in the US too. Also "she's a worrywart."

Answer (score 51):

This is a noun, but such a person is a [worrywart](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worrywart). It is frequently used to describe loved ones who are overly concerned about your well being. It fits perfectly into your example sentences.

> My mother is *a worrywart*.
>
> I want to tell my mother about my flight tonight, but, you know, she
>   is *a worrywart* and will lose sleep worrying over my safety.

This word is very informal, but not derisive. It typically implies some measure of affection.

The expression is used mainly in  ***[American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worrywart%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cworrywart%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworrywart%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworrywart%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)***.

[Worry wart](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=worry%20wart):

> 1956, from comic strip "Out Our Way" by U.S. cartoonist J.R. Williams (1888-1957). According to those familiar with the strip, Worry Wart was the name of a character who caused others to worry, which is the inverse of the current colloquial meaning.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 29):

This state of mind has a rich tradition in Victorian times, where upper-class females had little to spend their time on. An entirely appropriate term for it would be [***high-strung***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high%E2%80%93strung).

> Having an extremely nervous or sensitive temperament.
>   *"I'm not blaming my kid, but she's very high-strung."*

Reference:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high-strung

Comment: This phrase has the least baggage as far as associations, while still expressing the meaning.

Comment: This is what I'd use.

Comment: +1, but I've always heard "highly strung" rather than "high strung". [google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=high-strung%2Chighly+strung%2Chigh+strung%2Chighly-strung&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chigh%20-%20strung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20strung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chigh%20strung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20-%20strung%3B%2Cc0) shows both in use, possibly it's a regional variation.

Comment: @AndyT I also suspect it's regional. I've never head "highly", always "high". Northeast US

Comment: "High[ly] strung" sounds more like she gets upset easily, like she might cry or snap at you with little provocation, than like she's unreasonably worried.

Answer (score 22):

**'Neurotic'** is another word that would fit. Like 'paranoid' it has, or had, a strict mental health definition, and a looser idiomatic one, implying a tendency to worry excessively over little things.

**Edit**: Interestingly there is more emphasis on the medical aspect in the [Br Eng definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/neurotic) in the Cambridge:

> Br: behaving strangely or in an anxious (= worried and nervous) way, often >because you have a mental illness
>
> US: related to or having unreasonable anxiety or unusual behavior

Comment: Good word choice - why not add a dictionary definition to support your answer?

Comment: This was my first thought as well.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Done!

Comment: But please indicate which dictionary/ies you have quoted from - preferably using a web link.

Answer (score 13):

Not a single word, of course, but you could say your mother is a **[nervous Nellie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nervous%20Nellie)**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> :  a timid or worrisome person
>
> ...
>
> My sister is a real nervous Nellie when it comes to flying.

Or, in your example sentence:

I want to tell my mother about my flight tonight, but, you know, she is a nervous Nellie and will lose sleep worrying over my safety.

Comment: I've heard negative Nellie more than I've heard nervous Nellie.

Comment: @ringo If [this](https://www.quora.com/Where-did-the-phrase-Negative-Nellie-originate) answer on Quora is correct, 'Negative Nellie' is a more recent term, having been popularized by US President Johnson ca. 1966. Unrelated, but perhaps interesting, a few years later we have US Vice President Agnew's ["nattering nabobs of negativism"](http://politicaldictionary.com/words/nattering-nabobs-of-negativism/) (written by White House speechwriter William Safire).

Answer (score 12):

***Over [apprehensive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apprehensive)*** is a term you can use in the context you are describing:

> - Anxious or fearful that something bad or unpleasant will happen:
>
>   - ‘*he felt apprehensive about going home’*

- My mother is over apprehensive.

(ODO)

Comment: I've only heard overly apprehensive.

Answer (score 12):

[**Paranoid**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paranoid) should work here.

> **Unreasonably or obsessively anxious**, suspicious, or mistrustful <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

I hope I'm correct in assuming that you want a word which describes the nature of someone being worried easily, not a word to describe their current state of worry.

As in:

> I hope my mother doesn't find out how risky this is, she's paranoid. = (She's not worried right now, but she will be if she learns of this; that's her nature.)

EDIT: As is common knowledge, I hope, the word paranoid refers to a mental disorder in its primary sense. However, its usage in the metaphorical sense is quite common, and doesn't necessarily imply that you think she suffers from this illness. (English is littered with metaphorical usages of medical conditions, with varying degrees of social acceptance: "Are you blind?" "Are you deaf?" "Are you insane?").

The more noteworthy thing here is what @Peter points out in the comments: that the word is also used metaphorically in a different sense -- to suggest a fear of persecution.

In any case, like thousands of other words with multiple meanings, I don't think you'll have any trouble getting your meaning across, given the proper context.

I advise the detractors to familiarize themselves with the concept of [Etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: Yes. I want to express the fact that she has a predisposition toward getting worried over simple things. Example: If I have to fly tonigh, I know that my mother will get worried about it the moment I tell her that.

Comment: @Explorer: That's what I figured. Words like edgy/apprehensive won't work in that case. They come into play _after_ she becomes worried. They're not really apt to describe her inherent quality of being worried easily.

Comment: Exactly. So, I guess Paranoid is the right one?

Comment: @Explorer: I'd say so. But let's wait and see if someone comes up with a better suggestion. IMO, the other answers currently are just synonyms of 'worried', not synonyms of 'someone who worries a lot'.

Comment: 'Paranoid' is often used this way idiomatically, but strictly speaking it is a medical term for severe mental illness and best avoided in a formal context. Similarly the use of 'schizophrenic' in a loose way to mean something like 'ambivalent' or 'unclear intent'  is discouraged in style guides etc. That said, if you want to misuse a medical term, 'neurotic' might be a better fit . . .

Comment: @peterG: What you said is correct. However, it's also well-known enough to warrant omission from the post, IMO. (I'll consider adding it if I get more feedback along these lines.) That said, your bit about `neurotic` is interesting. You could post that as an answer. Personally though, I associate 'neurotic' more with stress than worry. So a wouldn't call it a 'better' fit.

Comment: Well, we are talking about very loose usage of the terms here, but I associate 'paranoid' with 'they're all out to get me', (suspicious or mistrustful, in your quoted definition) and 'neurotic' with 'have I left the back door unlocked', so . . . .

Comment: @peterG: Fair enough. That sense of paraboid is indeed more common. I'll say it again, you should post it as an answer. The OP might not read all the comments. (Meanwhile, I see neurotic as shaky hands and nail-biting. I'd still use paranoid for unlocked door.)

Answer (score 8):

The word can be 'Jittery' or 'Restive'
There are many simple words which fit the exact same description.

> My mother is very **jittery**.
>
> My Mother is very **restive**.
>
> My Mother is very **nervous**.

P.S. Use a phrase instead.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a phrase for that?

Comment: use, "on pins and needles" instead  'My mother is always on pins and needles.' @Explorer

Comment: Doesn't it mean something like 'fingers crossed'?

Comment: @Explorer Yes. It means, 'nervously agitated'. but can also be used in a contextual sense as nervous or jumpy.. 'Paranoid' works good as well..

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there are so many simple words in English that mean exactly what you're looking for that I don't even find it very practical to list them all here except for a couple of the most commonly used ones.

> My mother is very **jumpy**.
>
> My mother is very **edgy**.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect definitional fit, but ***[frantic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frantic)*** is the exact word I'd use for my mother, er, your mother.

The exact definition is more active, rather than prone to the feeling. Typically, you will see something like "we were frantically searching ..." However, I find

> My mother is very frantic

or

> My mother is a frantic person

quite fitting.

Comment: The modern accepted definition of "frantic" ("marked by fast and nervous, disordered, or anxiety-driven activity") does not apply to someone who merely worries on behalf of someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The word that my mother would use to describe such a person is **panicky.**
That is, prone to "panic."

Answer (score -2):

[flighty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flighty)

From Merriam Webster:

> Definition of flighty
>
> ...
>
> 2 :  lacking stability or steadiness:
>
> ```
>  a :  easily upset :  volatile <a flighty temper>
>  b :  easily excited :  skittish <a flighty horse>
>  c :  capricious, silly
> ```
>
> Examples of flighty in a sentence:
>
> "an actress who specializes in playing silly, flighty women"